# Button to hide/show a block in Safari (with Google Sites)

Tags: html, safari

I added at my website created with Google Sites a button to hide/show a block of text. The problem is that in Chrome/Firefox it works, but in Safari it does not work.
I did not use javascript/JQuery because in google sites is not simply to handle.

In the following the simple code i added.
How do I can solve this problem?

```html
<div class="nascosto">
  <input type="button" value="Abstract" onclick="
    if (this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display != '') 
     { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = ''; this.value = 'Abstract'; } 
    else { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = 'none'; this.value = 'Abstract'; }" />
</div><div><div class="nascosto" style="display: none;">
<p>Insert here
</p>

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for me there is an error in firefox, too. I've found out, that the next sibling of the first div is a text-element. I found this out with a console.log of the nodename. You can see it in the code-example below. For me the following code is working now, but I cannot test this in safari.

Also the function is not called childNodes, but children. Maybe this is a problem for safari.

Please put the functionality in an separate function on top or at the bottom of the page. The way you've done it is not really great.

```js
function doSomething(element) {
  console.log(element.parentNode.nextSibling.nodeName);
  if (element.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.children[0].style.display != 'block') {
    element.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.children[0].style.display = 'block';
    this.value = 'Abstract';
  } else {
    element.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.children[0].style.display = 'none';
    this.value = 'Abstract';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide">
  <input type="button" value="Abstract" onclick="doSomething(this)" />
</div>
<div id="test2">
  <div class="hide" style="display: none;">
    <p>Insert text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the site is made with Google Sites, i don't know where put the javascript code, for this i wrote the code in that way.